# In NamedParameterJdbcTemplate String not mapping properly with BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Below is the simple query to get a list of strings.

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT TAGS FROM FIN_REQUEST WHERE IS_CORPORATE_CONTENT IS TRUE AND TAGS IS NOT NULL";
List<String> data1 = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(String.class));
List<String> data2 = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new RowMapper<String>() {
    @Override
    public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getString(1);
    }
});
```

**data1** gives an empty list while **data2** is giving proper results. I want to avoid RowMapper and use BeanPropertyRowMapper instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeanPropertyRowMapper`, as the name implies, is for mapping columns to bean properties. You don't have a wrapper with a field of type String named `tags`. You are just returning a single `String`. So you cannot use the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

If you want to use it you need to create a wrapper object, which is probably not what you want. So you need to use the `RowMapper`. Assuming you are on Java 8 or up you can just use a lambda instead of in anonymous class.

```java
List<String> data2 = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, (rs, row) -> rs.getString(1));
```

However I see no use for the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` here (there are no named parameters) so you could also use the regular `JdbcTemplate` instead and use one of its methods.

```java
List<String> data2 = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlQuery, String.class);
```